# How to get $(this) within a function declared in href of an anchor tag

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following anchor tag in a td in my table:

```
<a  href="javascript:editAccount()" class="edit">edit</a>
```

I would like to find the parents of this td within my editAccount() function, doing the following:

```
function editAccount(){ console.log($(this).parent().parent()); }
```

However, I keep getting null in my console

Comment: Don't do this. Use real event handlers. You should *not* be using `href="javascript:` links anymore.

Comment: I never do but unfortunately in this project, the event handlers do not work at all, that is why I had to do the alternative...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need pass the element under question

```
<a  onclick="editAccount(this)" class="edit">edit</a>
```

and

```
function editAccount(elem){ console.log($(elem).parent().parent()); }
```

or using **[function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**.

```
<a  onclick="editAccount.call(this)" class="edit">edit</a>
```

and

```
function editAccount(){ console.log($(this).parent().parent()); }
```

Using Jquery to bind the event.

```
<a class="edit" href="#">edit</a>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('.edit').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log($(this).parent().parent());
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PBaUr/)**

Answer (score 5):

`this` does not refer to anything in that function.

Just add an actual event to the anchor:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
   console.log($(this).parent().parent());
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `href="javascript:editAccount()`, bind `editAccount` using standard event registration via jQuery:

```
$(".edit").on("click", editAccount);
```

You can also use an anonymous function instead of defining `editAccount` separately.

In case the `.edit` links are added dynamically, you can use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit", function (e) {
    //prevent following the link if you want
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log($(this).closest("td"));
});
```